# Cabinet door swings open by itself

Tags: cabinets, hinges

The cabinet door swings open by itself. Is there any way to adjust this hinge?

Thank you very much in advance. [image]

Comment: Should be, but might is easier to place magnetic catches to keep the door close.

Comment: Those two screws on the face-frame side of the hinge give you some horizontal and vertical adjustment, but that might not be your issue.  Is the face frame plumb?  If it's leaning out into the room, it'll dump that door open.

Comment: The spring that holds it closed is tired or broken. Easiest is to replace it. Search Blum face frame and match the existing overlay.

Answer (score 2):

The closing mechanism on these hinges is not adjustable. They are supposed to "lock" in the closed position. You can verify this by removing the hinge and operating it back and forth. The good news is that these hinges are readily available at many home stores. Just bring the old hinge with you when shopping for the new one.